# Dynamic delegation in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

We have two classes - User and Group

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Group Memberships
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Group has a property called 'name'
  # Group members
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :members, through: :memberships, source: :user
end
```

This is working just fine and we can create Groups and add Users to those groups.

What's the cleanest way to detect user's group membership? Something like: user.reviewer? where reviewer is the name of a group, without explicitly defining those methods. How can this be done using delegation?

We already have it working, albeit in an ugly way. Would appreciate the most elegant (and shortest) solution.

PS: We're on Rails 4.2.7

Comment: For that kind of work I would suggest you look into [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit). They already have that functionality, and they allow you to extend it with your own code easily without bothering with DSL's. It works well with Devise, and is a pure joy to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I looked `delegate` wasn't supported for `has_many` relationships.

The simplest way is to define a `member_of?` method. I'm doing it here with a private method and using a memoized list of group names.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Group Memberships
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
  delegate :name to :groups

  def member_of?(group_name)
    group_names.include? group_name.to_s
  end

  private

  def group_names
    @group_names ||= groups.pluck(:name)
  end

end
```

Use it like...

```
my_user.member_of?(:reviewers)
```

If you keep group names in the singular, you can still do the more readable pluralize call...

```
 my_user.member_of?(:reviewers)
```

And just reference the argument as `group_name.to_s.singularize` in the method.

Note that you can support `my_user.reviewer?` by adding a `def method_missing` call, but you'd have to 
check that the method is a valid group name and then check whether the user is a member of the group, otherwise raise the missing method error (i.e. `super` to the inherited `method_missing`).  See here for a simple explanation of how `method_missing` can be used.  https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Respond_to_an_unknown_method_call#Ruby

Comment: Thanks Steve. This is exactly how we're doing it currently. Wondering if try and inspect can somehow be used here.

Comment: Well, this solution is only two one-line methods and is about as efficient as you can get, so I'm not sure what you're trying to improve. You may be going for excessive refactoring here.  If you're really eager to have `my_user.reviewer?` work then see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is a way you can get `my_user.reviewer?` to work...  add the following to your User class:

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  if name.to_s.end_with?('?')
    group_name = name.to_s.chomp('?')
    if Group.find_by(name: group_name)
      return groups.pluck(:name).include?(group_name) ? true : false
    end
  end
  super
end
```

Comment: Two issues with this - 1) if the group doesn't exist, it hides the wrong method call and, 2) it explicitly returns true/false in a ternary.

Comment: No if the group doesn't exist it falls through to `super` so the inherited `method_missing` takes control. It only returns `true` or `false` once it knows that the group exists (I. E. That `reviewer' in `reviewer?` is a group name

Comment: Did my response clarify? There is a test here to ensure we're looking at a group name else we do standard `method_missing`.  If it is a group name,  only then do we return true or false depending on whether we belong to the group.